# how to do cross-validation for block kriging?

Tags: r, cross-validation, automap

I have written a code in automap package to cross-validate different kriging techniques. I have cross-validated all of them, but I cannot write the code for Block kriging. It shows this error:

unused argument (block=c(400,400))

```
library(automap)
mydata<-read.table(".../mydata.txt",header=T,sep=",")
colnames(mydata)=c("x","y","data1")
library(gstat)
coordinates(mydata)=~x+y
mygrids<-read.table(".../grids.txt",header=T,sep=",")
gridded(mygrids)=~x+y
block_kriging_cv<-autoKrige.cv(log(data1)~x+y, mydata, mygrids, block=c(400,400), model=c("Ste"), nfold=10)
```

Now, please let me know how I can fix it. The final step after fixing this will be compare.cv of all cv s, am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This means that the autoKrige.cv command does not take in account the blocks of your data. It performs the cross-validation point-by-point and not by blocks.

Cross validation takes in account the accuracy of the estimates of the interpolation (or prediction) for POINTS while block kriging is a smoothing method  that divides the whole area into several BLOCKS and calculate the local average of your estimations for each of those area. In other words, for the area 'block' you don't have a 'value' to compare your estimation made by kriging

Comment: Thanks @Fabio, but after all, how can I make sure that the estimates this method gives, is not better than simple, ordinary or universal kriging. Because SSE map of the block kriging method has less values than others. So, I am not sure how to decide and tell which one is proposed as the most suitable interpolation method.

Comment: I would use only simple, ordinary and universal kriging. And getting informative statistics from the cross validation of these three methods. Cross-validation of a block kriging is not trivial.

Comment: I did the same. Thanks a lot @Fabio.

Comment: Dear @Fabio, could you also write a code to:  1.calculate the spatial mean, and 2. calculate standard decviation or variance of the kriging result? Thanks